# Ban the [none] tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

#### <s>Title: The [none] tag should not disable pretty printing</s>

<s>I just noticed that questions tagged with [none](/questions/tagged/none) disables normal pretty printing  in the question as if applying `lang-none` to the code blocks.  Apparently it's given higher precedence than some tags.  Questions also [tagged python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681048/using-a-if-statement-condition-to-see-null-user-input-and-print-sometext) will have no pretty printing using `lang-none`.  While having both [c++ and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190349/none-in-boost-python) will have `lang-default` (I guess it invoked the rule applying `lang-default` when multiple non-none known tags could be applied).</s>

<s>Could it be set to where the [none](/questions/tagged/none) tag doesn't apply anything and just have the default settings?</s>

<s>or at the very least,</s>

<s>Give it the lowest precedence over all tags.</s>

---

After much deliberation, perhaps it would be better to just request a ban on the [none](/questions/tagged/none) tag as it's a contextual tag and useless on its own.

Comment: Why is there a [none] tag at all? What purpose does it serve? The questions mostly seem to revolve around "none" being a text string outputted by code or a language keyword, which, if valid, would make tags like [the] and [true] valid as well.

Comment: It appears to be used for questions that deal with the `display: none` CSS property, too. But its impact is pretty limited; there are only 33 total `[none]` questions. (@Mark)

Comment: @Mark: Frankly it doesn't have any purpose other than people just adding it because they can.  New askers often write in the tag line some phrase that relates to their problem without understanding what the tags do.  Those who have the ability to make new tags introduce these and it sticks.  I suppose we could turn this around and be a request to ban the tag all together since it doesn't work alone, but there's only a few questions tagged (a ban on a rarely used tag seems like overkill to me).  But if that's something the team wouldn't mind doing, then I'm all for it.

Comment: if the two choices are to change the syntax highlighting logic for a little used tag that's used incorrectly or to blacklist a little used tag that's used incorrectly, the blacklist is almost certainly the easier (and preferable) of the two.

Comment: @Mark: To be honest, I couldn't see any reason why we'd want this tag in particular to disable prettify.  I'm not saying that putting `lang-none` on any tag is pointless, there might be valid uses on some tags, I just don't see why this tag needed this specifically.  As I understand it, all tags default to not applying anything hence my request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag has nothing to do with prettify, so the entire premise of your question is .. incorrect.

However, this tag is a very bad one and it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Just as good.  I changed this request to be a blacklist one instead to reflect on the action taken.  So it is no longer an issue.